# How to know a component's render times

Tags: reactjs

As the title shows, Can i know how many times when a class component or a functional component render? Is there any chrome extension or webpack plugin?And now i just can get this by console.log

just console.log to log the times

Comment: Use react profiler (react dev tools) to get better idea about component rendering.
it's a chrome extension.

Comment: Asking for tools, libraries, tutorials ,or off-site resources recommendation is off-topic in here

Comment: I don't think in this case he's off-topic. He's asking for a way to profiling the render time, so pretty on-topic IMHO

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`react-devtools`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/15/new-react-devtools.html):

1. Install [`react-devtools` extension](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#profiling-components-with-the-devtools-profiler).
2. While on a development environment, excess your browser dev tools.

[image]

2. Go to `Profiler` tab
3. Press `Start-Profiling`

[image]

4. Examine the snapshot

[image]

> Dashboard Component (`0.6ms of 86.ms`) - Rendered at `1.3 for 83ms`

Refer to official walkthrough video of the profiler [on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nySib7ipZdk).